# Set up mesosphere chronos cluster

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I am using chronos as timer service and need set up a cluster in case one of them goes down unexpectedly. I set up mesos master/slaves, zookeeper, and added mesos master/zookeeper addresses to each chronos node. What I got finally:
1. each chronos node shared the same jobs data
2. one chronos node as a framework was registered to mesos master
3. I ran curl -IL for each node but didn't get redirected to the leading node. As the doc (https://mesos.github.io/chronos/docs/faq.html#which-node) says, I should be redirected.

By following the clustering guide (https://github.com/Metaswitch/chronos/blob/dev/doc/clustering.md), I created the chronos_cluster.conf and restarted all nodes, nothing changed. I guess I failed to get the chronos cluster running correctly. Did I missing something or did anything wrong? I didn't found a guide on http://mesos.github.io/chronos/docs/. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. In fact all nodes share same zookeeper, then they run on a cluster. I saw the log message saying "INFO Proxying request to ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:4400 . (org.apache.mesos.chronos.scheduler.api.RedirectFilter:37)"